# is groovy regex (slightly broken)?

Tags: regex, groovy

```
println "p(cat || cats, n)" ==~ /^p\(.+||.+,sn\)$/
println "" ==~ /^p\(.+||.+,sn\)$/
```

why does the 2nd line return true? Is this a bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` is a special character that means "OR" and needs to be escaped to obtain a literal `|`. The second regex returns true because `||` matches the empty string (between the two "OR")

Note there is no "s" after the comma in the first string but a space.

Comment: I considered escaping it before posting this, but maybe I don't know how to escape? Because `println "p(cat || cats, n)" ==~ /^p\(.+\|\|.+,sn\)$/` returns false.

also, the 's' is for space

Comment: @mvhatch your quoting is ok, but the `s` is wrong. `/^p\(.+\|\|.+,\sn\)$`.  A random `s` is _not_ "for space".  `\s` is for a whitespace.